# Gathering statistics on how a program is used

Tags: python, usage-statistics

I have a few programs that do similar things, but they're written in different languages. I want to somehow monitor the way the programs I write are used - how many times is the code ran? How many times is a particular method/function used? How long did it take to compile?

My goal with this is to get a graphical representation so that I can easily compare the programs in pretty graphs - because of this I obviously need my solution to be language independent.

What would be the best way to approach this task? Someone hinted me towards Ganglia but I'm not sure that's exactly what I'm looking for - I don't want to monitor clusters, I want to monitor the way different pieces of code is handled.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend looking at [sentry](https://docs.getsentry.com/on-premise/). It's free and has clients for many languages.

Basic usage:

```
import time
from raven import Client

client = Client('https://<key>:<secret>@app.getsentry.com/<project>')


start_time = time.time()
some_func()
client.captureMessage("Execution time of some_func %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to write one thing that will work no matter the language, instead of adding something for each language then option 1, for me, would be to write a wrapper for all of the programs, and replace the originals. You don't mention your operating system, but on Linux I would do the following:

```
$ cat wrapper.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is my logging statement"
exec /path/to/real/scripts/$(basename $0) $*
```

Then move all your scripts to `/path/to/real/scripts` and replace the original locations with a symlink to the wrapper script:

```
bar -> wrapper.sh
foo -> wrapper.sh
```

So when you call `foo` from the original location, it runs the wrapper, which knows it was called with the name `foo` and so can locate the real script to run after it's done its logging.

For collecting the data, something like Graphite (http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html), InfluxDB (https://influxdata.com/) or similar is probably easiest to set up.

The longer term, 'We thought of this in advance' option is to have the coding standards say 'Log program use to this location', as it avoids the wrapper and makes things easier to manage.